# Embed rich text with CATextLAyer

Tags: ios, database, text, layer, catextlayer

I am already able to add a layer with text in it using CATextLayer. However I'm finding the way the text is presented pretty basic. I would like to write paragraphs with quotes, in bold sometimes, italic etc...

Is there a way to do it with CATextLayer?

If not, how could I manage it, especially if the text is pulled out of a database?

I would like to be able to write the following text this way for instance:

"The article was about employment. He leafed through it in an instant. His feeling of anxiety resurfaced and he closed the magazine.

-Hm…, he breathed.

-Have you been looking for work long?, asked the stranger at his side."

Thanks

Comment: to make paragraph you don't need rich text. just add `\n` for a newline.

Comment: Rich Text isn't possible AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need rich text if all you want to do is line breaks. add a `\n` for a newline. So:

```
layer.text=@"The article was about employment. He leafed through it in an instant. His feeling of anxiety resurfaced and he closed the magazine.\n\n-Hm…, he breathed.\n\n-Have you been looking for work long?, asked the stranger at his side."
```

---

Real Rich Text isn't possible AFAIK

Comment: it doesn't work for me. CATextLayer has the .string property.